# Stationarity after differencing

Tags: time-series, stationarity, unit-root

I have the following two processes:
\begin{align}
x_t &= x_{t-1} + u_t  \tag{1}  \\
x_t &= {\beta}_0 + {\beta}_1t + u_t  \tag{2}
\end{align}

Differencing once leads to:

\begin{align}
\Delta x_t &= u_t  \tag{1}  \\
\Delta x_t &= {\beta}_1 + u_t + u_{t-1}  \tag{2}
\end{align}

From my notes, I understand that process (1) is stationary as $u_t$ is a white noise process. However, my lecture notes also state that process (2) is not stationary.

Why is process (2) not stationary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $E[u_t]=0$ and $\beta_1 \not = 0$ then in the second question $$E[x_t]-E[x_{t-1}] = E[\Delta x_t] = \beta_1 \not = 0$$ which imples the process is not stationary.

Comment: What if B_1 is a constant? The first condition for stationarity is that the process must be constant in mean, so if B_1 is a constant, the condition is satisfied

Comment: If $\beta_1$ is a non-zero constant then $E[x_t]$ is increasing with $t$, so the original process is not constant in mean.

Comment: @Henry first process is stationary after differencing, second contains unit root in MA process...

Answer (score 1):

First process is stationary in differences but non-stationary in levels.

Second process is linear time trend and is non-stationary in levels. It is non-stationary also in differences since it contains non-invertible root in the MA(1) process. But you can easily see that deviation from the mean trend is white noise just by subtracting constant and trend value from the y(t).